# Disappearing shapes in button template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Something strange is going on when I try to use a button style I created on multiple buttons in my app. I created 2 button templates for a Play and Pause button. I change to style depending on the playstate. There is more than 1 Window that has a play/pause button. The Polygons disappear for all but one of the buttons for some reason but the rest of the style (colors, pressed colors, etc) still works.

I'm setting the button styles like:

```
btnTelPlay.Style = (Style)FindResource("PlayButtonGreen");
btnTelPlay.Style = (Style)FindResource("GreenPause");
```

Here are the styles:

```
 <Style x:Key="PlayButtonGreen" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Polygon Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Points="5,0  5,30, 30,15" Fill="White" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="#FF3DEE2B"
                        BorderBrush="#404040">
                        <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="BorderBrush" Value="#202020" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="BorderBrush" Value="#202020" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="Background" Value="#FF3DEE2B" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="Background" Value="#FF39C72B" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="BorderBrush" Value="#606060" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="BorderBrush" Value="#AAAAAA" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="GreenPause" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Width="10" Height="30" Fill="White" Margin="0,0,2.5,0"></Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Width="10" Height="30" Fill="White" Margin="2.5,0,0,0"></Rectangle>
                </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="#FF3DEE2B"
                        BorderBrush="#404040">
                        <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="BorderBrush" Value="#202020" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="BorderBrush" Value="#202020" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="Background" Value="#FF3DEE2B" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="Background" Value="#FF39C72B" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="BorderBrush" Value="#606060" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="BorderBrush" Value="#AAAAAA" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: How do you set a style for buttons in code? It must be so, if the styles are in `<Window.Resources>`: `PlayButton.Style = this.Resources["PlayButtonGreen"] as Style;`. If styles in `App.xaml`, then: `PlayButton.Style = Application.Current.Resources["PlayButtonGreen"] as Style;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is that you're setting the `Content` property to something that isn't a `Freezable`. This means that WPF won't be able to easily copy it to a new instance of the `Style`. If you just replace your `ContentPresenter` with whatever you're setting in the `Content` `Setter`, it should work.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain it very well. To put it another way, I am getting the correct resources for the correct buttons as long as there is only 1 each of each button (1 play, 1 pause, 1 stop). When I open up a second window (now 2 of each button) the buttons on the new window is stealing the polygons/rectangles from the other buttons on the original window and I am left only with the colors on the original window.

Comment: @user2697208 I updated the answer to hopefully address your issue.

Comment: Thanks, Abe, for helping me figure this out!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Abe Heidebrecht, you led me to the correct way to achieve the results I wanted:

Instead of this:

```
<Setter Property="Content">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Polygon Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Points="5,0  5,30, 30,15" Fill="White" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I removed that from `<Setter Property="Content">` and put it in ControlTemplate like:

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="#FF3DEE2B"
                        BorderBrush="#404040">
                        <Polygon Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Points="5,0  5,30, 30,15" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
```

So for example here is one of the completed style/templates:

```
 <Style x:Key="PlayButtonGreen" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="#FF3DEE2B"
                        BorderBrush="#404040">
                        <Polygon Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Points="5,0  5,30, 30,15" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="BorderBrush" Value="#202020" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="BorderBrush" Value="#202020" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="Background" Value="#FF3DEE2B" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="Background" Value="#FF39C72B" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="BorderBrush" Value="#606060" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                          Property="BorderBrush" Value="#AAAAAA" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```